# Add line "Draft: Please do not quote or cite" to the maketitle

Tags: titles, article, draft

I'd like to add a `\fbox` with "Draft: Please Do Not Quote or Cite" at the top right of my title page which I generate with maketitle.

Does somebody know how to elegantly add the line `\fbox{\small Draft: Please Do Not Quote or Cite}` to the title?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\title{
    \vspace{-15mm}
    \fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textbf{\ttitle} % title defined above
    }   
\author{
    \large
    \textsc{...}\\[2mm]
    \vspace{-5mm}
    }
\date{\normalsize \today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the »[titling](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling)« package to customize the title according to your ideas.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-15mm}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{%
  \begin{center}
    \large \lineskip 0.5em%
    \scshape
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\vspace{-3mm}\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}\normalsize}
\postdate{\par\end{center}}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{
  \vspace{-60pt}
  \raggedleft
  \small
  \fbox{Draft: Please Do Not Quote or Cite}%
  \vspace{60pt}%
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I've tried all three options (thank you, guys!). At the end, this one turned out to be the only functioning for me, since I was heavily modifying maketitle myself.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following rather simple solution suit you? Specify your title using the `\mydrafttitle` command. The rest is like your everyday use. No extra package needed.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\newlength\titlepageskip\setlength{\titlepageskip}{50.0mm}

\long\def\mydrafttitle#1{\title{\vspace*{-\titlepageskip}\hfill\fbox{\small Draft: Please Do Not Quote or Cite}\\[\titlepageskip]#1}}

\mydrafttitle{Paper Title}

\author{Author Name}

\date{Paper Date}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And here is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of the `titling` package, but Thorsten was quicker than me. `:)` Here's a third approach with patching `\maketitle` and adding a boolean flag:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newboolean{draftmode}

\newcommand{\enabledraft}{\setboolean{draftmode}{true}}

\newcommand{\draftnote}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{draftmode}}{%
\vspace{-3em}%
\begin{flushright}
\framebox{\small Draft: please do not quote or cite}
\end{flushright}}{}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{2em}{2em \draftnote}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}
\enabledraft

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore, while I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, as of someone gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door. Tis some visitor, I muttered, tapping at my chamber door. Only this, and nothing more.]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid redefining basic things, there is a convenient and flexible interface via [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en). In case you need the running head, you can redefine it later. Page number placement adjustment also becomes much easier. This avoids any hardcoding that may break things defined in other packages you are likely to be using.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For blind text

\title{My PhD thesis}
\author{John Thomas}
\date{September 99, 2021}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\fbox{\small Draft: Please Do Not Quote or Cite}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

% The rest goes here
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Title page text frame Do not circulate 1draft]